# Iterate over a df and delete all rows with date before a given date point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a pd dataframe that looks like the following:

| id | projet_id | date_cod | date | year | month | p50 | p90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DCLT | 30-03-2022 | 01-01-2022 | 2022 | 1 | 5313.79 | 4571.03 |
| 2 | DLCT |  | 01-02-2022 | 2022 | 2 | 2350.25 | 1880.70 |
| 3 | DLCT |  | 01-03-2022 | 2022 | 3 | 2450.25 | 1763.90 |
| 4 | DLCT |  | 01-01-2023 | 2023 | 1 | 2180.25 | 1280.70 |
| 5 | DLCT |  | 01-02-2023 | 2023 | 2 | 4871.03 | 5224.03 |
| 6 | MADD | 01-01-2023 | 01-01-2022 | 2022 | 1 | 4575.03 | 1280.70 |
| 7 | MADD |  | 01-02-2022 | 2022 | 2 | 4331.03 | 5718.03 |
| 8 | MADD |  | 01-03-2022 | 2022 | 3 | 4331.03 | 1235.75 |
| 9 | MADD |  | 01-04-2023 | 2023 | 4 | 1224.00 | 1280.70 |
| 10 | MADD |  | 01-05-2023 | 2023 | 5 | 1480.70 | 1330.70 |
| 11 | PEYRS | 01-03-2024 | 01-01-2024 | 2024 | 1 | 1280.70 | 1280.70 |
| 12 | PEYRS |  | 01-05-2024 | 2024 | 5 | 1200.70 | 1235.75 |

Based on the `date_cod`,

For each `projet_id` (DCLT, MADD, PEYRS), I want to delete the `p50` and `p90` records that have their `date` value before the `date_cod`.

The output df should look like this.

| id | projet_id | date_cod | date | year | month | p50 | p90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DCLT | 30-03-2022 | 01-01-2022 | 2022 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | DLCT |  | 01-02-2022 | 2022 | 2 |  |  |
| 3 | DLCT |  | 01-03-2022 | 2022 | 3 |  |  |
| 4 | DLCT |  | 01-01-2023 | 2023 | 1 | 2180.25 | 1280.70 |
| 5 | DLCT |  | 01-02-2023 | 2023 | 2 | 4871.03 | 5224.03 |
| 6 | MADD | 01-01-2023 | 01-01-2022 | 2022 | 1 |  |  |
| 7 | MADD |  | 01-02-2022 | 2022 | 2 |  |  |
| 8 | MADD |  | 01-03-2022 | 2022 | 3 |  |  |
| 9 | MADD |  | 01-04-2023 | 2023 | 4 | 1224.00 | 1280.70 |
| 10 | MADD |  | 01-05-2023 | 2023 | 5 | 1480.70 | 1330.70 |
| 11 | PEYRS | 01-03-2024 | 01-01-2024 | 2024 | 1 |  |  |
| 12 | PEYRS |  | 01-05-2024 | 2024 | 5 | 1200.70 | 1235.75 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#Make sure dates are in to_datetime
df['date_cod']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_cod'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#Condition:date column is less (in total seconds) than first date for each projet_id's first date_cod value
cond=((df['date']-df.groupby('projet_id')['date_cod'].transform('first')).dt.total_seconds())<0

import numpy as np

#replace by '' where condition defined above is true
df['p50']=np.where(cond,'',df['p50'])
df['p90']=np.where(cond,'',df['p90'])
df
```